# Android -> Audio video merge with main video sound remaining the audio lower volume

Tags: android

I can merge a video with another audio nicely. But I also need main video sound in final output video. That means I want to set audio sound with low volume and main video sound remain same. I have done this in iOS - objective c using AudioMixer to low the volume

I have done following this in iOS. I need the similar things in Android
ref : [Audio video merge with main video sound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41987316/audio-video-merge-with-main-video-sound)

Comment: use ffmpeg sdk for android

Comment: @VivekMishra , thanks for your swift response . Would you kindly help me in detail..

Comment: ffmpeg is a third party sdk used to manipulate audio and videos. You can use that for Android